# Android Studio BUILD SUCCESSFUL even with evident errors in code

Tags: android

I have an Android Studio (Bumblebee 2021.1.1) project, composed of a main app plus two imported libraries, one Java and one native, developed by me.
At a certain point in time - I cannot recall any event related to this, - the compiler has stopped recognizing the code changes. 
If I write something random (e.g. my name, or "aaaaa") within a code that has thus far compiled successfully , the IDE marks this in red as error, however, when I press Ctrl+F9 ("Make Project"), the compiler does not detect any change in code and ends with "BUILD SUCCESSFUL". This happens also when I explicitly save the modified code. The only way I have to make the compiler detect the change is to launch "Rebuild Project". 
I have tried all the solutions proposed in Android communities (delete ".idea" and ".gradle" folders, invalidate cache, etc.), to no avail. 
 To be noted that I have other projects on the same PC with the same Android Studio instance, but the always-successful-build only happens with the project mentioned above.
 
Can anybody please  help me? This is very frustrating, because, even for a tiny code modification, I have to rebuild all, which is very time consuming. Thank you very much.